# PostgreSQL: how to see which table RULEs exists

Tags: postgresql, triggers, rules

We are using `RULEs` on tables instead of TRIGGERs for auditing purposes.

Is there a way to see which rules exist (`information_schema` perhaps)?

Also, can I see the source of the rules? Something similar to `pg_proc` maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is stored in `pg_rewrite`

You can use a query like this to rules for all tables in the `public` schema:

```
select r.rulename, 
       c.relname as rule_table,
       case r.ev_type  
         when '1' then 'SELECT' 
         when '2' then 'UPDATE' 
         when '3' then 'INSERT' 
         when '4' then 'DELETE' 
       end as rule_event, 
       pg_catalog.pg_get_ruledef(r.oid, true) as definition
from pg_catalog.pg_rewrite r  
  join pg_catalog.pg_class c on r.ev_class = c.oid 
where c.relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
  and r.rulename <> '_RETURN';
```

The `r.rulename <> '_RETURN'` excludes rules created for views.